# Triggering API call from SQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sql-server, database-trigger

I created a MySQL Database with a table, that needs to be populated with data from from another Database table (Microsoft SQL).

To accomplish this I made an API in Expressjs that is able to query the database and retrieve the data from the table(Microsoft SQL) then insert it in the MySQL table.

The issue is, that this needs to be manually done, and that causes the MySQL table out of sync with the Microsoft SQL table, causing bottlenecks and issues. ( setting a timer, will make too many requests)

Is there a way, to have my API called every time a new entry is inserted into the table? 
Better yet, is there a more elegant way to sync the different DB tables?

Comment: Maybe [MariaDB's connect engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-table-types-overview/) with ODBC/JDBC (there maybe bugs, but you can try). Re-evaluating why you need different concurrent database engines might useful. Or changing the application interfaces to SQL Server to update MySQL at the same time.

Comment: I have a client that is attempting to use test an interface I have built. Data needs to be updated between databases within 5 minutes. Before doing a migration, want to see how much it fills his need as expected. So re-evaluating database setups is not within the scope of this at this time.